# Gamma function $(-1)!$

Tags: factorial, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

How would you show that $(-1)!$ is infinite? I think you need to use the gamma function but I'm not entirely sure because I don't think the gamma function works for negative reals

Comment: The gamma function "works" for negative reals.  It is undefined for negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\int_0^\infty u^se^{-u}\:du=\Gamma(s+1),\quad s>-1. \tag1
$$ Then, integrating by parts, one gets
$$
\Gamma(s+1)=s\:\Gamma(s),\qquad s>0, \tag2
$$ giving
$$
\Gamma(s)=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}s,\qquad s>0, 
$$ and, as $s \to 0^+$,
$$
\Gamma(s)\sim\frac1s 
$$ yielding
$$
\lim_{s \to 0^+}\Gamma(s)=+\infty
$$ Then, if one defines $'(-1)!'$ as $'\Gamma(0)'=\lim_{s \to 0^+}\Gamma(s)$ , one obtains the announced result.

Answer (score 0):

One needs two conditions for the factorial:

1. $n!=n(n-1)!$
2. $1!=1$

So it becomes clear that

$$1!=1\times0!\implies0!=1$$

$$0!=0\times(-1)!\implies(-1)!=1/0\to\pm\infty$$

Anytime a division by $0$ occurs, the factorial (and the gamma function) diverge to $\pm\infty$.  This occurs at the negative integers.

The gamma function, on the other hand, does not diverge over the negative reals (except at the negative integers).  Examine that $\Gamma(-1/2)=-2\sqrt\pi$, for example.

Comment: How do you know that the gamma function diverges at the negative integers?

Comment: @Faolan It follows the conditions set above on the factorial, so if $(-1)!$ does not exist, neither will any negative integer or corresponding gamma function

Comment: @Faolan See that $(-2)!=-2(-1)!$ which still diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following

$$\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$$

Then we clearly see that

$$\Gamma(x+1) = x(x-1)\cdots(x-n)\Gamma(x-n)$$

That implies the gamma function diverges for non-positive integers.

Comment: Um, this is not so clear... and it misses the original question...

Comment: $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$ isn't a definition; it's a proposition we can prove to be true.  As it is apparently true, it implies $\Gamma(x)$ is undefined for negative integersl.  But that's not good enough to state that.  The question still stands why do we show that directly.  Also your observation isn't complete "clear".  This implication $\Gamma(-n-1) = (-1)^n/n!*k; k = \Gamma(-1)$ which is ... feasable.  What fails is noting $\Gamma(n+1) = n!*0*\Gamma(-1) = 0$ for positive $n$.  So $\Gamma$ can't work on both positive an negative integers.  But we need to show it directly.